# Mock in PHPUnit - multiple configuration of the same method with different arguments

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

Is it possible to configure PHPUnit mock in this way?

```
$context = $this->getMockBuilder('Context')
   ->getMock();

$context->expects($this->any())
   ->method('offsetGet')
   ->with('Matcher')
   ->will($this->returnValue(new Matcher()));

$context->expects($this->any())
   ->method('offsetGet')
   ->with('Logger')
   ->will($this->returnValue(new Logger()));
```

I use PHPUnit 3.5.10 and it fails when I ask for Matcher because it expects "Logger" argument.
It is like the second expectation is rewriting the first one, but when I dump the mock, everything looks ok.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As of PHPUnit 3.6, there is [`$this->returnValueMap()`](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs.examples.StubTest5.php) which may be used to return different values depending on the given parameters to the method stub.

Comment: Yeah, you can use returnValueMap() but ensure you specify all the parameters that the method needs or it doesn't work properly. See https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/issues/89

Answer (score 65):

Sadly this is not possible with the default PHPUnit Mock API.

I can see two options that can get you close to something like this:

### Using ->at($x)

```
$context = $this->getMockBuilder('Context')
   ->getMock();

$context->expects($this->at(0))
   ->method('offsetGet')
   ->with('Matcher')
   ->will($this->returnValue(new Matcher()));

$context->expects($this->at(1))
   ->method('offsetGet')
   ->with('Logger')
   ->will($this->returnValue(new Logger()));
```

This will work fine but you are testing more than you should (mainly that it gets called with matcher first, and that is an implementation detail).

Also this will fail if you have more than one call to each of of the functions!

---

### Accepting both parameters and using returnCallBack

This is more work but works nicer since you don't depend on the order of the calls:

### Working example:

```
<?php

class FooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {


    public function testX() {

        $context = $this->getMockBuilder('Context')
           ->getMock();

        $context->expects($this->exactly(2))
           ->method('offsetGet')
           ->with($this->logicalOr(
                     $this->equalTo('Matcher'), 
                     $this->equalTo('Logger')
            ))
           ->will($this->returnCallback(
                function($param) {
                    var_dump(func_get_args());
                    // The first arg will be Matcher or Logger
                    // so something like "return new $param" should work here
                }
           ));

        $context->offsetGet("Matcher");
        $context->offsetGet("Logger");


    }

}

class Context {

    public function offsetGet() { echo "org"; }
}
```

This will output:

```
/*
$ phpunit footest.php
PHPUnit 3.5.11 by Sebastian Bergmann.

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "Matcher"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Logger"
}
.
Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 3.00Mb

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

I've used `$this->exactly(2)` in the matcher to show that this does also work with counting the invocations. If you don't need that swapping it out for `$this->any()` will, of course, work.

Comment: Great solution! I agree with you that the order of the calls should not leak into the tests. However, with the second approach you get no guarantee if the method was called once with each individual expected value. That is to say, in your example the code could call context twice with `Matcher` as argument and never with `Logger` as argument and it would still pass. Depending on the test that might be an issue. How do you work around that without leaking order into the test case?

Comment: @MarijnHuizendveld "A closure that binds an array of expected calls, removes everyone that it has seen and a assertEmpty at the end of test" would be the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: Do note that ->at($x) includes function calls to other methods, so if you mock another method first, regardless of it being the same method or it using ->at($x) itself, $x starts at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Still $this->returnCallback is the only solution for this :/

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve this with a callback:

```
class MockTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider provideExpectedInstance
     */
    public function testMockReturnsInstance($expectedInstance)
    {
        $context = $this->getMock('Context');

        $context->expects($this->any())
           ->method('offsetGet')
           // Accept any of "Matcher" or "Logger" for first argument
           ->with($this->logicalOr(
                $this->equalTo('Matcher'),
                $this->equalTo('Logger')
           ))
           // Return what was passed to offsetGet as a new instance
           ->will($this->returnCallback(
               function($arg1) {
                   return new $arg1;
               }
           ));

       $this->assertInstanceOf(
           $expectedInstance,
           $context->offsetGet($expectedInstance)
       );
    }
    public function provideExpectedInstance()
    {
        return array_chunk(array('Matcher', 'Logger'), 1);
    }
}
```

Should pass for any "Logger" or "Matcher" arguments passed to the Context Mock's `offsetGet` method:

```
F:\Work\code\gordon\sandbox>phpunit NewFileTest.php
PHPUnit 3.5.13 by Sebastian Bergmann.

..

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 3.25Mb

OK (2 tests, 4 assertions)
```

As you can see, PHPUnit ran two tests. One for each dataProvider value. And in each of those tests it made the assertion for `with()` and the one for `instanceOf`, hence four assertions.

Answer (score 5):

Following on from the answer of @edorian and the comments (@MarijnHuizendveld) regarding ensuring that the method is called with both Matcher and Logger, and not simply twice with either Matcher or Logger, here is an example.

```
$expectedArguments = array('Matcher', 'Logger');
$context->expects($this->exactly(2))
       ->method('offsetGet')
       ->with($this->logicalOr(
                 $this->equalTo('Matcher'), 
                 $this->equalTo('Logger')
        ))
       ->will($this->returnCallback(
            function($param) use (&$expectedArguments){
                if(($key = array_search($param, $expectedArguments)) !== false) {
                    // remove called argument from list
                    unset($expectedArguments[$key]);
                }
                // The first arg will be Matcher or Logger
                // so something like "return new $param" should work here
            }
       ));

// perform actions...

// check all arguments removed
$this->assertEquals(array(), $expectedArguments, 'Method offsetGet not called with all required arguments');
```

This is with PHPUnit 3.7.

If the method you are testing doesn't actually return anything, and you simply need to test that it is called with the correct arguments, the same approach applies. For this scenario, I also attempted doing this using a callback function for $this->callback as the argument to the with, rather than returnCallback in the will. This fails, as internally phpunit calls the callback *twice* in the process of verifying the argument matcher callback. This means that the approach fails as on the second call that argument has already been removed from the expected arguments array. I don't know why phpunit calls it twice (seems an unnecessary waste), and I guess you could work around that by only removing it on the second call, but I wasn't confident enough that this is intended and consistent phpunit behaviour to rely on that occurring.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to type out an example! Very helpful. :)

Answer (score 4):

My 2 cents to the topic: pay attention when using at($x): it means that expected method call will be the ($x+1)th method call on the mock object; it doesn't mean that will be the ($x+1)th call of the expected method. This made me waste some time so I hope it won't with you. Kind regards to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled on this PHP extension to mock objects: https://github.com/etsy/phpunit-extensions/wiki/Mock-Object

Answer (score 0):

Here are also some solutions with the [doublit](https://getdoublit.com) library :

Solution 1 : using `Stubs::returnValueMap`

```
/* Get a dummy double instance  */
$double = Doublit::dummy_instance(Context::class);

/* Test the "offsetGet" method */
$double::_method('offsetGet')
    // Test that the first argument is equal to "Matcher" or "Logger"
    ->args([Constraints::logicalOr('Matcher', 'Logger')])
    // Return "new Matcher()" when first argument is "Matcher"
    // Return "new Logger()" when first argument is "Logger"
    ->stub(Stubs::returnValueMap([['Matcher'], ['Logger']], [new Matcher(), new Logger()]));
```

Solution 2 : using a callback

```
/* Get a dummy double instance  */
$double = Doublit::dummy_instance(Context::class);

/* Test the "offsetGet" method */
$double::_method('offsetGet')
    // Test that the first argument is equal to "Matcher" or "Logger"
    ->args([Constraints::logicalOr('Matcher', 'Logger')])
    // Return "new Matcher()" when first argument $arg is "Matcher"
    // Return "new Logger()" when first argument $arg is "Logger"
    ->stub(function($arg){
        if($arg == 'Matcher'){
            return new Matcher();
        } else if($arg == 'Logger'){
            return new Logger();
        }
    });
```