# In PHPUnit, how do I indicate different with() on successive calls to a mocked method?

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I want to call my mocked method twice with different expected arguments. This doesn't work because `expects($this->once())` will fail on the second call.

```
$mock->expects($this->once())
     ->method('foo')
     ->with('someValue');

$mock->expects($this->once())
     ->method('foo')
     ->with('anotherValue');

$mock->foo('someValue');
$mock->foo('anotherValue');
```

I have also tried:

```
$mock->expects($this->exactly(2))
     ->method('foo')
     ->with('someValue');
```

But how do I add a with() to match the second call?

Comment: Why do you need to match the arguments? Couldnt you use onConsecutiveCalls() to say "the first time, returns this, second time returns that"? You'd use exactly(2) and onConsecutiveCalls()

Comment: the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484602/mock-in-phpunit-multiple-configuration-of-the-same-method-with-different-argume) from the related block.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpunit mock method multiple calls with different arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988616/phpunit-mock-method-multiple-calls-with-different-arguments)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You need to use `at()`:

```
$mock->expects($this->at(0))
     ->method('foo')
     ->with('someValue');

$mock->expects($this->at(1))
     ->method('foo')
     ->with('anotherValue');

$mock->foo('someValue');
$mock->foo('anotherValue');
```

Note that the indexes passed to `at()` apply across all method calls to the same mock object.  If the second method call was to `bar()` you would not change the argument to `at()`.

Comment: Conscious that this is an old reply, In the recent versions of PHPUnit, the `at()` method has been officially deprecated, so `withConsecutive()` should be used going forward.

Answer (score 32):

Referencing from [the answer from a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988616/phpunit-mock-method-multiple-calls-with-different-arguments#answer-23942979),

Since PHPUnit 4.1 you can use `withConsecutive` eg.

```
$mock->expects($this->exactly(2))
     ->method('set')
     ->withConsecutive(
         [$this->equalTo('foo'), $this->greaterThan(0)],
         [$this->equalTo('bar'), $this->greaterThan(0)]
       );
```

If you want to make it return on consecutive calls:

```
  $mock->method('set')
         ->withConsecutive([$argA1, $argA2], [$argB1], [$argC1, $argC2])
         ->willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls($retValueA, $retValueB, $retValueC);
```

It's not ideal to use `at()` if you can avoid it because [as their docs claim](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html)

> The $index parameter for the at() matcher refers to the index, starting at zero, in all method invocations for a given mock object. Exercise caution when using this matcher as it can lead to brittle tests which are too closely tied to specific implementation details.

Comment: Yeah, it's a really stupid solution in phpunit. Everyone is misled by this fact eg https://addshore.com/2015/08/misled-by-phpunit-at-method/

Answer (score 2):

`withConsecutive` is deprecated too.
There is a solution in this post:
[Replace PHPUnit method `withConsecutive`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75389000/replace-phpunit-method-withconsecutive)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34300102)