# phpunit mock method multiple calls with different arguments

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

Is there any way to define different mock-expects for different input arguments? For example, I have database layer class called `DB`. This class has method called `Query(string $query)`, that method takes an SQL query string on input. Can I create mock for this class (`DB`) and set different return values for different Query method calls that depends on input query string?

Comment: In addition to the answer below, you can also use the method in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484602/mock-in-phpunit-multiple-configuration-of-the-same-method-with-different-argum

Comment: I like this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10964562/614709

Answer (score 153, accepted):

The PHPUnit Mocking library (by default) determines whether an expectation matches based solely on the matcher passed to `expects` parameter and the constraint passed to `method`. Because of this, two `expect` calls that only differ in the arguments passed to `with` will fail because both will match but only one will verify as having the expected behavior. See the reproduction case after the actual working example.

---

For you problem you need to use `->at()` or **`->will($this->returnCallback(`** as outlined in [**`another question on the subject`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484602/mock-in-phpunit-multiple-configuration-of-the-same-method-with-different-argume/).

### Example:

```
<?php

class DB {
    public function Query($sSql) {
        return "";
    }
}

class fooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {


    public function testMock() {

        $mock = $this->getMock('DB', array('Query'));

        $mock
            ->expects($this->exactly(2))
            ->method('Query')
            ->with($this->logicalOr(
                 $this->equalTo('select * from roles'),
                 $this->equalTo('select * from users')
             ))
            ->will($this->returnCallback(array($this, 'myCallback')));

        var_dump($mock->Query("select * from users"));
        var_dump($mock->Query("select * from roles"));
    }

    public function myCallback($foo) {
        return "Called back: $foo";
    }
}
```

### Reproduces:

```
phpunit foo.php
PHPUnit 3.5.13 by Sebastian Bergmann.

string(32) "Called back: select * from users"
string(32) "Called back: select * from roles"
.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 4.25Mb

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

---

---

### Reproduce why two ->with() calls don't work:

```
<?php

class DB {
    public function Query($sSql) {
        return "";
    }
}

class fooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {


    public function testMock() {

        $mock = $this->getMock('DB', array('Query'));
        $mock
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('Query')
            ->with($this->equalTo('select * from users'))
            ->will($this->returnValue(array('fred', 'wilma', 'barney')));

        $mock
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('Query')
            ->with($this->equalTo('select * from roles'))
            ->will($this->returnValue(array('admin', 'user')));

        var_dump($mock->Query("select * from users"));
        var_dump($mock->Query("select * from roles"));
    }

}
```

### Results in

```
 phpunit foo.php
PHPUnit 3.5.13 by Sebastian Bergmann.

F

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 4.25Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) fooTest::testMock
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-select * from roles
+select * from users

/home/.../foo.php:27

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Failures: 1
```

Comment: thanks for your help! Your answer completely solved my problem. P.S. Sometimes TDD development seems terrifying to me when I have to use such large solutions for simple architecture :)

Comment: This is a great answer, really helped me understand PHPUnit mocks. Thanks!!

Comment: You can also use `$this->anything()` as one of the parameters to `->logicalOr()` to allow you to provide a default value for other arguments than the one you're interested in.

Comment: Am wondering nobody mentions, that with "->logicalOr()" you won't guarantee that (in this case) both of the arguments have been called. 
So this doesn't really solve the problem.

Answer (score 280):

It's not ideal to use `at()` if you can avoid it because [as their docs claim](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html)

> The $index parameter for the at() matcher refers to the index, starting at zero, in all method invocations for a given mock object. Exercise caution when using this matcher as it can lead to brittle tests which are too closely tied to specific implementation details.

Since 4.1 you can use `withConsecutive` eg.

```
$mock->expects($this->exactly(2))
     ->method('set')
     ->withConsecutive(
         [$this->equalTo('foo'), $this->greaterThan(0)],
         [$this->equalTo('bar'), $this->greaterThan(0)]
       );
```

If you want to make it return on consecutive calls:

```
  $mock->method('set')
         ->withConsecutive([$argA1, $argA2], [$argB1], [$argC1, $argC2])
         ->willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls($retValueA, $retValueB, $retValueC);
```

PHPUnit 10 removed `withConsecutive`.  You can get similar functionality with:

```php
$mock->expects($this->exactly(2))
    ->method('set')
    ->willReturnCallback(fn (string $property, int $value) => match (true) {
        $property === 'foo' && $value > 0,
        $property === 'bar' && $value > 0 => $mock->$property = $value,
        default => throw new LogicException()
    });
```

Obviously way uglier and not quite the same, but that's the state of things.  You can read more about alternatives here: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/4026
and here: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/4026#issuecomment-825453794

Comment: Best answer as of 2016. Better than accepted answer.

Comment: How to return something different for those two different parameters?

Comment: @emaillenin using willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls in a similar way.

Comment: FYI, I was using PHPUnit 4.0.20 and receiving error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Builder_InvocationMocker::withConsecutive()`, upgraded to 4.1 in a snap with Composer and it's working.

Comment: The `willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls` killed it.

Comment: PHPUnit 10 deprecate at() and withConsecutive()!

Comment: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/5425

Answer (score 28):

From what I've found, the best way to solve this problem is by using PHPUnit's value-map functionality.

Example from [PHPUnit's documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs.examples.StubTest5.php):

```
class SomeClass {
    public function doSomething() {}   
}

class StubTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testReturnValueMapStub() {

        $mock = $this->getMock('SomeClass');

        // Create a map of arguments to return values.
        $map = array(
          array('a', 'b', 'd'),
          array('e', 'f', 'h')
        );  

        // Configure the mock.
        $mock->expects($this->any())
             ->method('doSomething')
             ->will($this->returnValueMap($map));

        // $mock->doSomething() returns different values depending on
        // the provided arguments.
        $this->assertEquals('d', $stub->doSomething('a', 'b'));
        $this->assertEquals('h', $stub->doSomething('e', 'f'));
    }
}
```

This test passes. As you can see:

- when the function is called with parameters "a" and "b", "d" is returned
- when the function is called with parameters "e" and "f", "h" is returned

From what I can tell, this feature was introduced in **PHPUnit 3.6**, so it's "old" enough that it can be safely used on pretty much any development or staging environments and with any continuous integration tool.

Comment: returnValueMap() use === to compare parameters: in case of Object that comparison failed as php documentation says https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php

Answer (score 6):

It seems Mockery (https://github.com/padraic/mockery) supports this. In my case I want to check that 2 indices are created on a database:

Mockery, works:

```
use Mockery as m;

//...

$coll = m::mock(MongoCollection::class);
$db = m::mock(MongoDB::class);

$db->shouldReceive('selectCollection')->withAnyArgs()->times(1)->andReturn($coll);
$coll->shouldReceive('createIndex')->times(1)->with(['foo' => true]);
$coll->shouldReceive('createIndex')->times(1)->with(['bar' => true], ['unique' => true]);

new MyCollection($db);
```

PHPUnit, this fails:

```
$coll = $this->getMockBuilder(MongoCollection::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
$db  = $this->getMockBuilder(MongoDB::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();

$db->expects($this->once())->method('selectCollection')->with($this->anything())->willReturn($coll);
$coll->expects($this->atLeastOnce())->method('createIndex')->with(['foo' => true]);
$coll->expects($this->atLeastOnce())->method('createIndex')->with(['bar' => true], ['unique' => true]);

new MyCollection($db);
```

Mockery also has a nicer syntax IMHO. It appears to be a tad slower than PHPUnits built-in mocking capability, but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

We are trying to upgrade out tests with Phpunit10 on PHP8.1 as annual upgrade of our images/libraries.
On Phpunit10 at() & withConsecutive() are deprecated.

[@Radu Murzea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995822/radu-murzea)'s solution works in most cases: not ours!
I need to mock MongoDB calls: parameters sometime are MongoDB\ObjectId; returnValueMap() use === to compare parameters reiceved: in case of Object that comparison failed as php documentation says php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php

my solution to mock MongoDB FindOne is the following:

```
    $map = [
        [
            ['_id' => new ObjectId("5825cfc1316f54c6128b4572"),],
            [],
            ['_id' => new ObjectId("5825cfc1316f54c6128b4572"), 'username' => 'test']
        ],
        [
            ['agencyIds' => new ObjectId("5825cfc1316f54c6128b4572"),],
            ['_id'],
            false
        ],
        [
            ['agencyIds' => new ObjectId("5825cfc1316f54c6128b4572"),],
            ['_id'],
            false
        ],
    ];

    $mongoDBUsersCollectionMock = $this->createMock(MongoDBCollection::class);
    $mongoDBUsersCollectionMock
        ->method('findOne')
        ->with($this->anything())
        ->will($this->returnCallback(
            function($filter, $options) use (&$map){
                list($mockedFilter, $mockedOptions, $mockedReturn) = array_shift($map);
                // if contains object remember don't use === because mean the exactly the same object
                // ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php
                if ($filter == $mockedFilter && $options == $mockedOptions){
                    return $mockedReturn;
                }
            }
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

## Intro

Okay I see there is one solution provided for Mockery, so as I don't like Mockery, I am going to give you a Prophecy alternative but I would suggest you first to [read about the difference between Mockery and Prophecy first.](http://everzet.com/post/72910908762/conceptual-difference-between-mockery-and-prophecy)

**Long story short**: "Prophecy uses approach called **message binding** - it means that behaviour of the method does not change over time, but rather is changed by the other method."

## Real world problematic code to cover

```
class Processor
{
    /**
     * @var MutatorResolver
     */
    private $mutatorResolver;

    /**
     * @var ChunksStorage
     */
    private $chunksStorage;

    /**
     * @param MutatorResolver $mutatorResolver
     * @param ChunksStorage   $chunksStorage
     */
    public function __construct(MutatorResolver $mutatorResolver, ChunksStorage $chunksStorage)
    {
        $this->mutatorResolver = $mutatorResolver;
        $this->chunksStorage   = $chunksStorage;
    }

    /**
     * @param Chunk $chunk
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function process(Chunk $chunk): bool
    {
        $mutator = $this->mutatorResolver->resolve($chunk);

        try {
            $chunk->processingInProgress();
            $this->chunksStorage->updateChunk($chunk);

            $mutator->mutate($chunk);

            $chunk->processingAccepted();
            $this->chunksStorage->updateChunk($chunk);
        }
        catch (UnableToMutateChunkException $exception) {
            $chunk->processingRejected();
            $this->chunksStorage->updateChunk($chunk);

            // Log the exception, maybe together with Chunk insert them into PostProcessing Queue
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

## PhpUnit Prophecy solution

```
class ProcessorTest extends ChunkTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var Processor
     */
    private $processor;

    /**
     * @var MutatorResolver|ObjectProphecy
     */
    private $mutatorResolverProphecy;

    /**
     * @var ChunksStorage|ObjectProphecy
     */
    private $chunkStorage;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->mutatorResolverProphecy = $this->prophesize(MutatorResolver::class);
        $this->chunkStorage            = $this->prophesize(ChunksStorage::class);

        $this->processor = new Processor(
            $this->mutatorResolverProphecy->reveal(),
            $this->chunkStorage->reveal()
        );
    }

    public function testProcessShouldPersistChunkInCorrectStatusBeforeAndAfterTheMutateOperation()
    {
        $self = $this;

        // Chunk is always passed with ACK_BY_QUEUE status to process()
        $chunk = $this->createChunk();
        $chunk->ackByQueue();

        $campaignMutatorMock = $self->prophesize(CampaignMutator::class);
        $campaignMutatorMock
            ->mutate($chunk)
            ->shouldBeCalled();

        $this->mutatorResolverProphecy
            ->resolve($chunk)
            ->shouldBeCalled()
            ->willReturn($campaignMutatorMock->reveal());

        $this->chunkStorage
            ->updateChunk($chunk)
            ->shouldBeCalled()
            ->will(
                function($args) use ($self) {
                    $chunk = $args[0];
                    $self->assertTrue($chunk->status() === Chunk::STATUS_PROCESSING_IN_PROGRESS);

                    $self->chunkStorage
                        ->updateChunk($chunk)
                        ->shouldBeCalled()
                        ->will(
                            function($args) use ($self) {
                                $chunk = $args[0];
                                $self->assertTrue($chunk->status() === Chunk::STATUS_PROCESSING_UPLOAD_ACCEPTED);

                                return true;
                            }
                        );

                    return true;
                }
            );

        $this->processor->process($chunk);
    }
}
```

## Summary

Once again, Prophecy is more awesome! My trick is to leverage the messaging binding nature of Prophecy and even though it sadly looks like a typical, callback javascript hell code, starting with **$self = $this;** as you very rarely have to write unit tests like this I think it's a nice solution and it's definitely easy to follow, debug, as it actually describes the program execution.

BTW: There is a second alternative but requires changing the code we are testing. We could wrap the troublemakers and move them to a separate class:

```
$chunk->processingInProgress();
$this->chunksStorage->updateChunk($chunk);
```

could be wrapped as:

```
$processorChunkStorage->persistChunkToInProgress($chunk);
```

and that's it but as I didn't want to create another class for it, I prefer the first one.